# Replacing identical NIC cards creates eth1 instead of using eth0 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet, replace

I changed out a NIC card that was the exact same make and model.  The setup process for Ubuntu 11.04 was very seemless and easy so I figured it would be smart enough to setup up the replacement card.  However, it gave the replacement card a new name of `eth1` where all my scripts make reference to `eth0`, not to mention everywhere else in the OS `eth0` may exist.  Am I forced to track down every `eth0` reference and change it to `eth1` or is there a way to rename the replacement card back to `eth0`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check udev config files.

A file like this:
    /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

ties the NAME (ethX) to the Mac address.

You probably have the old cards MAC tied to eth0. Remove its line and change the new card to eth0.

Comment: Thanks!  I did see in another post about the 70-persisten-net.rules file, but was in reference to fedora.  The file was just in a different location, but good know it is the same file.

Comment: To think I was using `ifrename(8)` and scratching my head! This solution is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the name of network interfaces either through udev (on any modern Linux system) or through [`/etc/network/interfaces`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&sektion=5) on Debian, Ubuntu and other distributions using [ifupdown](http://packages.debian.org/ifupdown). [Not Now's answer covers udev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24898/replacing-identical-nic-cards-creates-eth1-instead-of-using-eth0-in-ubuntu/24899#24899); I'll discuss ifupdown.

In `/etc/network/interfaces`, you can use the `mapping` directive to give a nicknames to an interface based on the result of running a shell script. Typical uses for this feature are to give interfaces different names based on the network surroundings (e.g. `eth0-home` and `eth0-work`) or to set the name of an interface based on its characteristics such as the MAC address. There is an example script called `get-mac-address.sh` that you can use to set the name of an interface based on its MAC.

```
auto eth0 eth1
mapping eth0 eth1
    script /usr/share/doc/ifupdown/examples/get-mac-address.sh
    map 11:22:33:44:55:66 lan
    map AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF internet
iface lan inet static
    address 192.168.42.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
iface internet inet dhcp
```

Now your two network interfaces are called `lan` and `internet`. If you ever replace one of them, you only need to update the MAC address in that one place in `/etc/network/interfaces`.